# What's the best way to parse an SQL fragment string into a List(of string) for a Listbox control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to take this string:

```
(("DISPLAY_NAME" like N'sadf%') And ("ID" = 2) And ("IsCRITERION" = null))
```

and parse it into a List(of string) so that it can be displayed like:

```
(
    (
        "DISPLAY_NAME" like N'sadf%'
    ) 
    And 
    (
        "ID" = 2
    ) 
    Or 
    (
        "IsCRITERION" = null
    )
)
```

I'm close but don't quite have it.  My code currently looks like:

```
Dim filterlist As New List(Of String)
Dim temp As String = String.Empty
Dim lvl As Integer = 0
Dim pad As String = String.Empty
For Each chr As Char In originalString  '--- filter is the string i posted above
    Select Case chr.ToString.ToLower()
        Case "("
            filterlist.Add(pad.PadLeft(lvl * 5) & chr)
            lvl += 1
        Case ")"
            filterlist.Add(pad.PadLeft(lvl * 5) & temp)
            If lvl > 0 Then lvl -= 1
            filterlist.Add(pad.PadLeft(lvl * 5) & chr)
            'If lvl > 0 Then lvl -= 1
            temp = String.Empty
        Case Else
            temp &= chr
    End Select
Next

'--- Removes the empty line produced by generating the List(of String)
filterlist = filterlist.Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList()

listSelectedCriteria.DataSource = filterlist
listSelectedCriteria.DataBind()
```

Unfortunately, the above code produces something close to what I desire but the "And"s and "Or"s are not in the right places:

```
(
    (
        "DISPLAY_NAME" like N'sadf%'
    ) 
    (
        And "ID" = 2
    )  
    (
        Or "IsCRITERION" = null
    )
)
```

Would using regular expressions be better?  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the "best" way (although that's getting into "primarily opinion-based" territory) would be to use a parser, but assuming that your input is limited to similar looking strings, here's what I came up with:

```vb
Dim originalString = "((""DISPLAY_NAME"" like N'sadf%') And (""ID"" = 2) And (""IsCRITERION"" = null))"
Dim filterlist = New List(Of String)()
Dim temp = New StringBuilder()
Dim lvl = 0
Dim addLine =
    Sub(x As String)
        filterlist.Add(New String(" ", lvl * 4) & x.Trim())
    End Sub
For Each c In originalString
    Select Case c
        Case "("
            If temp.Length > 0 Then
                addLine(temp.ToString())
                temp.Clear()
            End If
            addLine("(")
            lvl += 1
        Case ")"
            If temp.Length > 0 Then
                addLine(temp.ToString())
                temp.Clear()
            End If
            lvl -= 1
            addLine(")")
        Case Else
            temp.Append(c)
    End Select
Next
If temp.Length > 0 Then
    addLine(temp.ToString())
    temp.Clear()
End If

filterlist.Dump() ' LINQPad ONLY
```

This results in:

```
( 
    ( 
        "DISPLAY_NAME" like N'sadf%' 
    ) 
    And 
    ( 
        "ID" = 2 
    ) 
    And 
    ( 
        "IsCRITERION" = null 
    ) 
)
```

However, you will probably end up having to add code as you find different inputs that don't quite work how you want.

Comment: thanks so much!  i played around with several of the fragments in play and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at each characters, I would start be doing a split. And then add/remove padding depending on what character is at the start.

```
    Dim tempString As String = "((""DISPLAY_NAME"" like N'sadf%') And (""ID"" = 2) And (""IsCRITERION"" = null))"
    Dim curPadding As String = ""
    Const padding As String = "    "
    Dim result As New List(Of String)

    For Each s As String In Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(tempString, "(?=[\(\)])")
        If s <> "" Then
            If s.StartsWith("(") Then
                result.Add(curPadding & "(")
                curPadding &= padding
                result.Add(curPadding & s.Substring(1).Trim())
            ElseIf s.StartsWith(")") Then
                curPadding = curPadding.Substring(padding.Length)
                result.Add(curPadding & ")")
                result.Add(curPadding & s.Substring(1).Trim())
            Else
                result.Add(curPadding & s)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```